# Why are ^M and ^[ being appended to my files?

Tags: linux, vim, special-characters

I noticed that sometimes Vim shows `^M` at the end of every line, or `^[` in front of an opening bracket `[`.

What do these characters mean and how can I get rid of them?

I'm running Vim 7.3 on Debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are control characters. The *^M* represents the carriage return, used in windows as the other answer already explain.

The *^[* is the escape character. When followed by a opening square bracket ("[") it probably means an ANSI escape sequence. See this article to know more:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

And give it a try. For example, in your terminal:

```
echo ^[[7mHello World!^[[m
```

Where each *^[* can be inserted with <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>control</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>. So the sequence of typing is actually:

... <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>control</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>[</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> ...

Answer (score 3):

^M is dos-style line endings. You can get rid of them by using the dos2unix program:

dos2unix (yourfile)

Comment: actually it's a mixed line ending. If it were purely dos, vim would detect it as `[dos]` and `set fileformat=dos`.

Comment: What would cause these to be generated on a Linux machine? The file I have is a crontab log on a Debian box.

Answer (score 1):

These are control characters. [Here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/150/remove-m-characters-at-end-of-lines-in-vi/) is a link on how to remove them in vi.

Answer (score 1):

This article on Vim wiki should help you: [File format](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format).

Though the article title may seem to be different it does talk about line endings and unix/dos/macos file formats.

Comment: From the link, the relevant section is : Converting the current file :
A common problem is that you open a file and see ^M at the end of many lines. Entering :set ff? will probably show that the file was read as unix: the problem is that some lines actually end with CRLF. To fix this, you need to tell Vim to read the file again using dos file format. When reading as dos, all CRLF line endings, and all LF-only line endings, are removed. Then you need to change the file format for the buffer and save the file.